# Create Custom Policy using stable baseline3

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to create a custom lstm policy. It seems that BasePolicy is missing. How can we create a custom LSTM policy to pass to PPO or A2C algorithm. Also, if not, can modify the layer of lstm in the current setting that will help in customizing my results.

```
import gym
import torch.nn as nn
from sb3_contrib.common.policies import BasePolicy
from sb3_contrib.ppo_recurrent import RecurrentPPO


class CustomPolicy(BasePolicy):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomPolicy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def make_lstm_layer(self, n_lstm_layers: int) -> nn.Module:
        # Create your custom LSTM layer here
        # For example:
        lstm_layer = nn.LSTM(input_size=self.features_dim, hidden_size=64, num_layers=n_lstm_layers)
        return lstm_layer


env_name = "CartPole-v1"
env = gym.make(env_name)
model = RecurrentPPO(CustomPolicy, env, verbose=1)
```

Please guide.

I tried installing the packages but was unable to figure out how to create the custom policies or modify the policies they have provided

Answer (score 1):

LSTM-policies are not supported by sb3 out-of-the-box, but they are supported by `RecurrentPPO` from [sb3-contrib](https://sb3-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo_recurrent.html).